# Rails JSON API, token authentication PUT request

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, authentication, devise

I have my rails Blog App working using Devise for authentication and JSON API for logging in/logging out users with simple authentication token for Android.

If I'm logged in on a web browser it all works and I can do a Http PUT to upvote/downvote.

Questions: 
**In order to do a JSON put request for upvote/downvote in Android, I store the authentication token from login in a sharedPreferences and then pass it back, is that correct or am I meant to maintain the original login http request the entire time the app is open?**

**How do I know what requirements the json in my controller expects before allowing a logged in user to perform a PUT? I pass all the info back I would expect the votes table requires but I get the unauthorized 401 error**

Many thanks.

I have already logged in successfully in the Android app and pass my auth token back to the rails app before trying to upvote/downvote but I get this back in my rails app:

```
Started PUT "/articles/6/like" for 49.199.23.21 at 2016-03-14 01:02:44 +0000
Cannot render console from 49.199.23.21! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ArticlesController#upvote as JSON
  Parameters: {"votes"=>{"authenticity_token"=>"jQcV-m_MSKGeNJ-SGT4N", "id"=>"3", "votable_id"=>"6", "votable_type"=>"Article", "voter_id"=>"3", "voter_type"=>"User", "vote_flag"=>"t", "vote_weight"=>"1", "created_at"=>"2016-03-14 12:02:39.882000", "updated_at"=>"2016-03-14 12:02:39.882000"}, "id"=>"6", "article"=>{}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Whereas if I do it via HTML I get this (I note the authentication token is much longer):

```
Started PUT "/articles/5/like" for 137.147.172.125 at 2016-03-12 09:34:43 +0000
Cannot render console from 137.147.172.125! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ArticlesController#upvote as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"4eC8xgC+1CBb51gKO7ZRzjL1BGOF6TYTnbqQcJ3evxvpmGcguYHBNYSn9v3LJMfoo3F29frntwzgyLoeI9oaLg==", "id"=>"5"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Article Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "articles"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."voter_id" = ? AND "votes"."voter_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 5], ["votable_type", "Article"], ["voter_id", 1], ["voter_type", "User"]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "votes" ("votable_id", "votable_type", "voter_id", "voter_type", "vote_flag", "vote_weight", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["votable_id", 5], ["votable_type", "Article"], ["voter_id", 1], ["voter_type", "User"], ["vote_flag", "t"], ["vote_weight", 1], ["created_at", "2016-03-12 09:34:43.393685"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-12 09:34:43.393685"]]
   (11.4ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to https://completerubyonrailscourse-adam1st.c9users.io/articles/5
Completed 302 Found in 187ms (ActiveRecord: 13.2ms)
```

Logging in via Android:

```
    Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 49.199.23.21 at 2016-03-14 01:01:31 +0000
Cannot render console from 49.199.23.21! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"adam1st@hotmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "session"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"adam1st@hotmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "adam1st@hotmail.com"]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["last_sign_in_at", "2016-03-14 00:59:01.022130"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2016-03-14 01:01:31.196495"], ["sign_in_count", 28], ["updated_at", "2016-03-14 01:01:31.198628"], ["id", 3]]
   (13.9ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."authentication_token" = ?  [["authentication_token", "jQcV-m_MSKGeNJ-SGT4N"]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "authentication_token" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["authentication_token", "jQcV-m_MSKGeNJ-SGT4N"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-14 01:01:31.219386"], ["id", 3]]
   (10.8ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 166ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 26.5ms)
```

Routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: "registrations", sessions: "sessions", :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks"}
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root to: 'articles#index'
  resources :articles do
    member do
      put "like", to: "articles#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "articles#downvote"
    end
    resources :comments
  end
```

ArticlesController with the upvote/downvote:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
  before_filter :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:upvote, :downvote]

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
    if @article.save
      flash[:success] = "Article has been created"
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Article has not been created"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    if @article.user != current_user
      flash[:danger] = "You can only edit your own article"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end 

  def update
    if @article.user != current_user
      flash[:danger] = "You can only edit your own article"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      if @article.update(article_params)
          flash[:success] = "Article has been updated"
          redirect_to @article
      else
        flash.now[:danger] = "Article has not been updated"
        render :edit
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @comment = @article.comments.build
  end 

  def destroy
    if @article.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Article has been deleted"
      redirect_to articles_path
    end
  end
  def upvote
    @article.upvote_by current_user
    flash[:success] = "Successfully liked"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back }
      format.json { render json: { count: @article.liked_count } }
    end
  end
  def downvote
    @article.downvote_by current_user
    flash[:success] = "Successfully disliked"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back }
      format.json { render json: { count: @article.disliked_count } }
    end
  end

  private 
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
    end

    def set_article
    @article=Article.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

SessionsController:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
   self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
   sign_in(resource_name, resource)

   current_user.update authentication_token: nil

   respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render :json => {  :user => current_user, :status => :ok, :authentication_token => current_user.authentication_token } }
     format.html { super }
   end
  end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy

   respond_to do |format|
     format.json {
       if current_user
         current_user.update authentication_token: nil
         signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
         render :json => {}.to_json, :status => :ok
       else
         render :json => {}.to_json, :status => :unprocessable_entity
       end  

     }

     format.html{
      super
    } 
   end
  end
end
```

Voting Activity in Android:

```
private class VoteTask extends UrlJsonAsyncTask {
        public VoteTask(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPut put = new HttpPut(urls[0]);
            JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject voteObj = new JSONObject();
            String response = null;
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            try {
                try {
                    // setup the returned values in case
                    // something goes wrong
                    json.put("success", false);
                    json.put("info", "Something went wrong. Retry!");
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    String id = sharedPreferences.getString("userId", "default value");
                    String authToken = sharedPreferences.getString("AuthToken", "default value");

                    voteObj.put("authenticity_token",authToken);
                    voteObj.put("id",id);

                    voteObj.put("votable_id",articleId);
                    voteObj.put("votable_type", "Article");
                    voteObj.put("voter_id", id);
                    voteObj.put("voter_type", "User");
                    voteObj.put("vote_flag", voteFlag);
                    voteObj.put("vote_weight", "1");
                    voteObj.put("created_at", strDate);
                    voteObj.put("updated_at", strDate);
                    holder.put("votes", voteObj);
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
                    put.setEntity(se);

                    // setup the request headers
                    put.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    put.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

                    //ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    //response = client.execute(post, responseHandler);
                    //json = new JSONObject(response);

                    response = String.valueOf(client.execute(put));
                    json = new JSONObject(response);


                /*} catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("ClientProtocol", "" + e);
                    json.put("info", "Email and/or password are invalid. Retry!");*/
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("IO", "" + e);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("JSON", "" + e);
            }

            return json;
        }
```

Login Activity in Android which is working:

```
private class LoginTask extends UrlJsonAsyncTask {
        public LoginTask(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
            webClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
            JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject userObj = new JSONObject();
            String response = null;
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            try {
                try {
                    // setup the returned values in case
                    // something goes wrong
                    json.put("success", false);
                    json.put("info", "Something went wrong. Retry!");
                    // add the user email and password to
                    // the params
                    userObj.put("email", username);
                    userObj.put("password", password);
                    holder.put("user", userObj);
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
                    post.setEntity(se);

                    // setup the request headers
                    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    response = webClient.execute(post, responseHandler);
                    json = new JSONObject(response);

                } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("ClientProtocol", "" + e);
                    json.put("info", "Email and/or password are invalid. Retry!");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("IO", "" + e);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("JSON", "" + e);
            }

            return json;
        }
```

Votes Schema:

```
    create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "votable_id"
    t.string   "votable_type"
    t.integer  "voter_id"
    t.string   "voter_type"
    t.boolean  "vote_flag"
    t.string   "vote_scope"
    t.integer  "vote_weight"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "votes", ["votable_id", "votable_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_votable_id_and_votable_type_and_vote_scope"
  add_index "votes", ["voter_id", "voter_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_voter_id_and_voter_type_and_vote_scope"
```

Comment: I notice it's complaining about these connections not coming from `localhost`; have you tried running the server with the option `--binding=0.0.0.0`?

Comment: Every time I run the rails server I bind it using 0.0.0.0: rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8080 (I'm running this on cloud9)

Answer (score 0):

I went to the git of Simple token authentication https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication and saw this.

Authentication Method 2: Request Headers

You can also use request headers (which may be simpler when authenticating against an API):

X-User-Email alice@example.com

X-User-Token 1G8_s7P-V-4MGojaKD7a

so I put that in my vote task in the headers before performing my vote and it worked.

I now also know I don't need to maintain the original http request, I just put the two headers in before each request to prove i'm an authorized user.